# Automatically resolving dependencies by type-hinting on a static method in a custom class

Tags: laravel, php-7

In Laravel, there's a way to inject a dependency to a controller when it's needed. For example, in a class

```
class Foobar {
    private $obj;

    public function __construct(Obj $obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function bar(Obj $obj) {...}
}
```

The way to inject the needed `Obj` is to put some sort of binding on a Service Provider, [as seen here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers). However, I'm planning to make a dynamic library class `Baz`, and has static methods inside.

```
class Baz {
    public static function bazmethod(Obj $obj) {...}
}
```

Is it possible to resolve by type-hinting in such a static setting?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. With what exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: worst-case you resolve it yourself inside the function? And I would like to say: just try it.

Comment: well, what happened is that I used the `bazmethod(Obj $obj)` function inside a controller and did not pass anything, since I already put a binding in the AppServiceProvider. Now it says that I didn't pass anything (none given) to the parameters, so therefore it didn't work. Does automatic resolving not work in static functions?